# Alternative to Access app

Tags: vba, excel

A subroutine in Excel VBA runs a macro in an Access database. This exports a table in the db to a .csv file. I have Access installed on my PC but other people that will also need to use this do not, so see an error message.

Is there any other method I can use to run a macro from Access besides creating an object as in my code below, maybe something like a ADODB?

My Excel VBA code:

```
Dim accApp As Object
Set accApp = CreateObject("Access.Application")


dbPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Database\STORE_TOC_FRONTEND.accdb"

accApp.OpenCurrentDatabase dbPath
accApp.DoCmd.RunMacro "Create SS Upload"

Set accApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah make an Adodb connection object, and a Adodb recordset object. Untested code below.

```
set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" 'Or Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 for 2007+ version of access
conn.Open "c:/webdata/northwind.mdb" 'path to your db

set objRecordset=CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
objRecordset.open("Select * from SomeTable",conn,0,3,1)

'do you work here, something like a loop for each field and for each row

objRecordset.close
conn.close
```